# Does the universe do "work" when a gas is cooled during it's expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity

So I think I've confused myself.

The Christoffel symbols are nothing more than the non-inertial forces (up to a proportionality constant of mass). So if I am in a thermalized box and I suddenly start spinning obviously the when I apply the $e^{-\beta H}$ partition function recipe to find the I should obviously not include the non-inertial forces in $H$.

However, if the box is in presence of a uniform gravitational field then I should apply the $\beta$ factor to Hamiltonian. Here's where it's confusing me. Consider our universe which is described by the FLRW metric. **Should the expansion done in the FLRW metric [(see here)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0603087.pdf) be considered as work?** Should I include the Christoffel symbols this time when I use $e^{- \beta H}$?

$$ \ddot{x^i} + \frac{2}{a} \frac{da}{dt} \frac{dt}{d\tau} \dot x^i= 0$$

Or:

$$  \frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{dt^2}   + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt} - \Gamma^0_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt} = 0$$

Multiplying with mass and integrating with respect to the displacement $ds$:

$$ \int m \frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{dt^2} ds   + m \int(\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt} - \Gamma^0_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt}) ds = E$$

Where $T = \int m \frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{dt^2} ds$ corresponds to the kinetic energy and $V =\int(\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt} - \Gamma^0_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt}) ds $ corresponds to the potential energy and $E$ is the total energy.

Now, in the classical mechanics regime should I apply $e^{-\beta T}$ or $e^{-\beta (T +V)}$?

**(How can/) Can this question even be answered within the framework of general relativity?** Let's go back to stress energy tensor of the flrw metric:

$$ T^{\mu \nu} = \langle \frac{p^{\mu} \otimes p^\nu}{p^0} \rangle$$

If I only feed in the average quantities it shouldn't be possible to answer this.

Answer (score -2):

It's been a long time since I've done hard physics, so if I mess up, I apologize, but e^{-\beta T} looks correct, but over all to answer your final question, no.

And that's a no because we still only have a theoretical and mathematical understanding of the universe's expansion process. All the practical experience we (humans) have with it is done in a sim lab or on pen and paper and not observed so again, it's based off our  theories on what we think we see, millions upon million of light years away. Best you could come up with is an estimate of the "work"the universe is doing when gas is cooled.

Like as said, as far as the equation, it has been a very long time since I've done this kinda physics, so if it's wrong I do apologize. I have a degree in biological physics, so it has been since my bachelor's degree and a few master level class since I've done this kind of physics (20 years ago)